# Setting up Payum Bundle with Symfony2 giving error

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, payment-gateway, payum

I am working with Symfony 2.6 and trying to setup PayumBundle (paypal express checkout) and I am getting an error

```
InvalidConfigurationException in BaseNode.php line 313: Invalid configuration for path "payum.security.token_storage": The storage entry must be a valid model class. It is set Acme\featuresBundle\Entity\PaymentToken
```

I am following the steps mentioned in there [documetation](http://payum.org/doc/0.13/PayumBundle/get_it_started)

This is how my `config.yml` looks like

```
    doctrine:
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
            entity_managers:
                default:
                    auto_mapping: true
                    mappings:
                        payum:
                            is_bundle: false
                            type: xml
                            dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/Bridge/Doctrine/Resources/mapping
                            prefix: Payum\Core\Model

    payum:
        security:
            token_storage:
                Acme\featuresBundle\Entity\PaymentToken: { doctrine: orm }

        storages:
            Acme\featuresBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails: { doctrine: orm }

        contexts:
            paypal:
                paypal_express_checkout_nvp:
                    username: 'asdasd'
                    password: 'adsasd'
                    signature: 'asdasdasd'
                    sandbox: true
```

This is my Entity `PaymentToken`

```
namespace Acme\featuresBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Payum\Core\Model\Token;

/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PaymentToken extends Token
{

}
```

And this is Entity `PaymentDetails`

```
namespace Acme\featuresBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Payum\Core\Model\Order as BaseOrder;

/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PaymentDetails extends BaseOrder
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     *
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

I have gone through alot of documentation online and other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425127/payum-symfony-2-bundle-basic-configuration-storage) but I dont understand why I am getting this error.

```
The storage entry must be a valid model class. It is set Acme\featuresBundle\Entity\PaymentToken
```

I cant even get to the controller so something tells me it is the `config.yml` configuration of Payum that is not set correctly. I have gone through the documentation over and over and over and I cant seem to find what am I doing wrong.

I will really appreciate any help in getting pass this error.

Comment: The exception is thrown [here](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/MainConfiguration.php#L194)  and it means that class_exists function cannot find your class `Acme\featuresBundle\Entity\PaymentToken`.  Start from autoloading settings, most probably you forget to configure it.

Comment: I did add the bundle in `registerBundles` method of `AppKernel` class if thats what you meant by auto load. I am not sure if creating entity manually causes the problem because that’s what I did and when I deleted those entity and recreated them using command `php app/console doctrine:generate:entity` and then re did the configuration it worked.

Comment: I meant not a bundle registration but php class autoloading feature. if you use composer you can setup it in your composer.json. https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Can you tell me where is this mentioned in payum documentation

Comment: I have another issue, I was wondering if you can help me in that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169357/not-able-to-send-payment-to-paypal-using-symfony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get it done.

I needed 4 files

1. PaymentController
2. Orders (Entity)
3. PaymentToken (Entity)
4. Orders (Model)

This is my `PaymentController` looks like

```
<?php

namespace ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Controller;

use ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Entity\Orders;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Api;
use Payum\Core\Registry\RegistryInterface;
use Payum\Core\Request\GetHumanStatus;
use Payum\Core\Security\GenericTokenFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration as Extra;


    class PaymentController extends Controller
    {
        public function preparePaypalExpressCheckoutPaymentAction(Request $request)
        {
            $paymentName = 'paypal';
            $eBook = array(
                'author' => 'Jules Verne',
                'name' => 'The Mysterious Island',
                'description' => 'The Mysterious Island is a novel by Jules Verne, published in 1874.',
                'price' => 8.64,
                'currency_symbol' => '$',
                'currency' => 'USD',
                'clientId' => '222',
                'clientemail' => 'xyz@abc.com'
            );



            $storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorage('ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Entity\Orders');
            /** @var $paymentDetails Orders */
            $paymentDetails = $storage->create();

            $paymentDetails->setNumber(uniqid());
            $paymentDetails->setCurrencyCode($eBook['currency']);
            $paymentDetails->setTotalAmount($eBook['price']);
            $paymentDetails->setDescription($eBook['description']);
            $paymentDetails->setClientId($eBook['clientId']);
            $paymentDetails->setClientEmail($eBook['clientemail']);


            $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = $eBook['currency'];
            $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = $eBook['price'];
            $paymentDetails['NOSHIPPING'] = Api::NOSHIPPING_NOT_DISPLAY_ADDRESS;
            $paymentDetails['REQCONFIRMSHIPPING'] = Api::REQCONFIRMSHIPPING_NOT_REQUIRED;
            $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0'] = Api::PAYMENTREQUEST_ITERMCATEGORY_DIGITAL;
            $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'] = $eBook['price'];
            $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'] = $eBook['author'].'. '.$eBook['name'];
            $paymentDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0'] = $eBook['description'];
            $storage->update($paymentDetails);
            $captureToken = $this->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken(
                $paymentName,
                $paymentDetails,
                'payment_done'
            );
            $paymentDetails['INVNUM'] = $paymentDetails->getId();
            $storage->update($paymentDetails);
            return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());


        }

        public function doneAction(Request $request)
        {

            $token = $this->get('payum.security.http_request_verifier')->verify($request);

            $payment = $this->get('payum')->getPayment($token->getPaymentName());

            // you can invalidate the token. The url could not be requested any more.
            // $this->get('payum.security.http_request_verifier')->invalidate($token);

            // Once you have token you can get the model from the storage directly.
            //$identity = $token->getDetails();
            //$order = $payum->getStorage($identity->getClass())->find($identity);

            // or Payum can fetch the model for you while executing a request (Preferred).
            $payment->execute($status = new GetHumanStatus($token));
            $order = $status->getFirstModel();

            // you have order and payment status
            // so you can do whatever you want for example you can just print status and payment details.

            return new JsonResponse(array(
                'status' => $status->getValue(),
                'response' => array(
                    'order' => $order->getTotalAmount(),
                    'currency_code' => $order->getCurrencyCode(),
                    'details' => $order->getDetails(),
                ),
            ));

        }

        /**
         * @return RegistryInterface
         */
        protected function getPayum()
        {
            return $this->get('payum');
        }
        /**
         * @return GenericTokenFactoryInterface
         */
        protected function getTokenFactory()
        {
            return $this->get('payum.security.token_factory');
        }

    }
```

This is my `Orders` Entity

```
<?php

namespace ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Model\Orders as BasePaymentDetails;

/**
 * Orders
 */
class Orders extends BasePaymentDetails
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    private $number;

    private $description;

    private $client_email;

    private $client_id;

    private $total_amount;

    private $currency_code;

    protected $details;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set number
     *
     * @param integer $number
     * @return Orders
     */
    public function setNumber($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get number
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Orders
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set client_email
     *
     * @param string $clientEmail
     * @return Orders
     */
    public function setClientEmail($clientEmail)
    {
        $this->client_email = $clientEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get client_email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getClientEmail()
    {
        return $this->client_email;
    }

    /**
     * Set client_id
     *
     * @param string $clientId
     * @return Orders
     */
    public function setClientId($clientId)
    {
        $this->client_id = $clientId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get client_id
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getClientId()
    {
        return $this->client_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set total_amount
     *
     * @param float $totalAmount
     * @return Orders
     */
    public function setTotalAmount($totalAmount)
    {

        $this->total_amount = $totalAmount;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total_amount
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getTotalAmount()
    {
        return $this->total_amount;
    }

    /**
     * Set currency_code
     *
     * @param string $currencyCode
     * @return Orders
     */
    public function setCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
    {
        $this->currency_code = $currencyCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get currency_code
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->currency_code;
    }

    /**
     * Set details
     *
     * @param string $details
     * @return Orders
     */
    public function setDetails($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get details
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDetails()
    {
        return $this->details;
    }
}
```

This is my `PaymentToken` Entity

```
<?php

namespace ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Payum\Core\Model\Token;

/**
 * PaymentToken
 */
class PaymentToken extends Token
{

}
```

This is my `Orders` model

```
<?php

namespace ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Model;

use Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject;

    class Orders extends ArrayObject
    {
        protected $id;
        /**
         * @return int
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    }
```

1. Now when I call the Action
   `preparePaypalExpressCheckoutPaymentAction` via route
2. I get redirected to make the payment
3. I can see the response in `doneAction`

Very neat library. Took me a while to figure it out and I am glad it works now. I am sure i have alot more to learn about Payum and I hope someone can confirm if this is the right way :)